# Avoid running multiple programs

Tags: process, application

Some programs, eg. `firefox`, allows to have multiple instances. Though, this is useful in some cases (eg. new `xterm` instance), I usually end up having enormous number.

Is it possible to configure which programs must have only one instance?

Comment: I don't think this is on the DE, but the application itself. Firefox allows users to start multiple instances of it in any DE or OS, but some applications like games do not. So, I feel this is beyond the scope of the DE, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Firefox does not allow multiple instances unless you go through hoops (you can only have one instance per profile). What do you mean by “have only one instance”, exactly? Do you mean that only a single process should be running? Only a single process as your user? Only a single window in your GUI session? Something else?

Comment: If you were hoping to have e.g. multiple xterm windows managed by the same process, that's impossible. It's a matter of how the application is written.

Answer (score 3):

I launch my GUI apps mostly with keyboard shortcuts, and for apps I only want one  instance of, I point those shortcuts to a wrapper that either gives me the last running instance (and puts that window to the front), or creates a new instance if there isn't one.

I have:

**lonew**:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#lastof or new -- try lastof and give me a new instance if it failed
cmd=$1; shift
lastof "$cmd" || exec "$cmd" "$@"
```

**lastof**:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#give me the last used instance of the GUI app matching $@

results=$(xdotool search "$@")
result=$(echo "$results" | 
    while read -r id; do echo "$(xprop -id $id '_NET_WM_USER_TIME')" "$id"; done | 
    sed -n 's/.*= //p' |sort -n |
    tail -1| cut -d\  -f2
)
[ -n "$result" ] || result=$(echo "$results" | tail -1)
exec xdotool windowactivate "$result"
```

To give an example, my shortcut settings to launch my terminal emulator are:

```
Ctrl+Alt+K : lonew konsole
Ctrl+Shift+Alt+K :  konsole #force a new instance
```

Some apps such as banshee or thunderbird effectively manage this one-instance thing by themselves, but I find it convenient to have a do-one-thing-and-do-it-well standalone solution for it which I can wrap around any app I want.

---

Dependencies: xprop, xdotool